# Locate/search directory in kaa sandbox ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, kaa

I am trying to execute DataCollectionDemo.jar in kaa sandbox ubuntu using Oracle VM Virtualbox. I have done all the prerequisites like using shared folder functionality and inserting guest additions. The folder is in kaa sandbox ubuntu. (When I drag over the shared folder icon at the bottom of the screen, I see it)

How can I search for the file I want to run in kaa sandbox ubuntu? I know the command line to run: $ java -jar DataCollectionDemo.jar Since it is shared, where is it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be sure that file DataCollectionDemo.jar  is exist in your shared folder on your host machine and then check this folder on guest machine again.

If this doesn't work do not hesitate to  use scp to copy it from one machine to another, run on your host:

`scp  path_to_the/DataCollectionDemo.jar guest_username@guest_host_ip:/remote/directory/`